# Extract all numbers from string in list

Tags: awk, sed, tr

Given some string 's' I would like to extract only the numbers from that string. I would like the outputted numbers to be each be separated by a single space.

> ## Example input -> output
>
> ....IN:`1,2,3`
>   OUT:`1 2 3`
>
> ....IN:`1 2 a b c 3`
>   OUT:`1 2 3`
>
> ....IN:`ab#35jh71 1,2,3 kj$d3kjl23`
>   OUT:`35 71 1 2 3 3 23`

I have tried combinations of `grep -o [0-9]` and `grep -v [a-z] -v [A-Z]` but the issue is that other chars like `-` and `#` could be used between the numbers. *Regardless* of the number of non-numeric characters between the numbers I need them to be replaced with a *single* space.

I have also been experimenting with `awk` and `sed` but have had little luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo 'ab#35jh71 1,2,3 kj$d3kjl23' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*'
35
71
1
2
3
3
23
```

```
$ echo 'ab#35jh71 1,2,3 kj$d3kjl23' | tr -sc '[:digit:]' ' '
 35 71 1 2 3 3 23
```

Comment: Should be `tr -sc '[:digit:]' ' '`

Comment: This solution is great! Very concise and easy to read! Could you please add an **Explanation** section to explain how ```-sc``` and the regex you used work?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about spaces in your expected output, based on your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/," ")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Globally substituting anything apart from digit with spaces. Mentioning `1` will print current line.

---

---

In case you want to remove initial/starting space and ending space in output then try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/," ");gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Globally substituting everything apart from digits with space in current line and then globally substituting starting and ending spaces with NULL in current line. Mentioning `1` will print edited/non-edited current line.